# Find coordinates of building in web game

Tags: web-scraping, web

I need to find the coordinates of buildings in a web game.

Hi,

I'm trying to find out the coordinates of all the mines in this [game](https://play.leagueofkingdoms.com/).
I know the coordinates of the mines is stored either in html, js variables, or local storage. But how do i go about finding it, and printing it to the console.

The only current solution i have is scrolling through the whole map and using text recogonition, finding mines on the screen, but that option is very slow to search the whole map.

Thanks!